# While loop using only mysql query language

Tags: mysql, function, triggers, while-loop

I have some trigger to save call records as blob into database. I want to add some extra function that will execute each time with trigger and will help to keep database in some size limits: function must do something like that:

Must calculate blob files' sum. while it's larger then given value, delete oldest record from table.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please take a look

```
WHILE ((select sum(OCTET_LENGTH(recordfile))/1000000 from callrecords)>0,1) 
DO
BEGIN
DELETE FROM callrecords ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
END;  
END WHILE;
```

Here is how database looks like

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `callrecords`
-- ----------------------------
CREATE TABLE `callrecords` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `callerid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `extension` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `calldate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `recordfile` longblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=350 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Thx in advance.

Comment: So, what happpens? Does your trigger run? Does it delete records? Do you get an error? What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You should select the blob file size into a variable outside of the loop, and then update the variable by re-running the select after each delete.

Code example based on your initial attempt:

```
declare v_size int;
...
-- initialize the variable
select sum(OCTET_LENGTH(recordfile)) 
into v_size
from callrecords;

while (v_size > 1000000)
do
  DELETE FROM callrecords ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;

  -- update the variable
  select sum(OCTET_LENGTH(recordfile))
  into v_size
  from callrecords;

end while;
```